# Tasks Schedules are not working in Sitecore Content Delivery

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

we are using Sitecore 6.6, we have the setup of Content Management(CM) and Content Delivery(CD). CM pointing to Master database and CD Pointing to Web database. Here, We have created Commands under sitecore/System/Tasks/Commands. By using that commands created Task Schedules under sitecore/System/Tasks/Schedules. Those task schedules are working fine on Content Management instance. However, the same is not working on Content Delivery instance. We have followed the Sitecore scaling guide for setting up the Content Delivery instance. However, we could not get succeeded on Tasks schedules.

Please help on this.

Thank you, 
Annadurai

Comment: I presume you have changed the database from master to web for `<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" .../>` and your interval and frequency settings are correct?

Comment: yes, I have modified the agent as follows,
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00">
        <param desc="database">web</param>
        <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
        <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
      </agent>

frequency is as follows 
      <frequency>00:05:00</frequency>
frequency set 5 mins and interval set 10 mins.

Comment: Is there anything noted in your log files?

Comment: I don't see any specific exception or error relevant to this. Also, I have raised ticket to sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are correct, your problem is related to settings on the CD servers - and not related to your Schedules, commands or scalabilitysettings.config. That being said; why not just run these scheuled tasks on the CM server?   Once for "master", once for "web".  If you have specific reasons for not wanting to do this, likely it would be because your commands and tasks are doing Things specific to the CD instance. In this case, likely this will also be the source of your problem. Either referencing an absolute path or whatnot, which exists on CM but not in CD.

Or in short; if you're sure of all of the below, please post more information on what is going on in your tasks and commands.

- All tasks and Schedules etc have been fully published to web. Switch to "web" and double check
- All assemblies and classes referenced from your command items, have been fully deployed to CD
- All necessary references from your assemblies containing commands have been deployed to CD
- The UrlAgent has been configured correctly on CD. Doublecheck that the server can call itself on the host name you have provided for it
- Database Agent is indeed running on CD. This WILL show in your logfiles.